# How to change the blog posts webpart properties using powershell?

Tags: web-part, powershell, blog

How to change the JSLink property of the Blog posts Web part in Default.aspx page of a blog site using powershell ? I tried the code below

```
$SPsite = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://blogpostsiteurl"  
  $webpartmanager = $SPsite.GetLimitedWebPartManager("/default.aspx",   
 [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)    

  for($i=0;$i -lt $webpartmanager.WebParts.Count;$i++)  {   
  if($webpartmanager.WebParts[$i].title -eq "Posts")   
  {    
     $wp=$webpartmanager.WebParts[$i];  
     $wp.JSLink="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/blogpost.js"; 
     $webpartmanager.SaveChanges($wp);  
     break;   
  }   
 }   
  $SPsite.Update();   
  $SPsite.Dispose();
```

But i get the error

```
Exception calling "GetLimitedWebPartManager" with "2" argument(s): "Value does
not fall within the expected range."
```

Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research , I got it

```
   $SiteURL = "http://blogsiteurl"  


    Function SetJSLinkPropertyOnPostsWebPart($SiteURL)
    { 

        $pagePath = "/default.aspx"
        $pageUrl = $SiteURL + $pagePath
        $web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL

        $spWebPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($pageUrl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

        foreach ($webpart in ($spWebPartManager.WebParts | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Posts"}))
        {
         $webpart.JSLink="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/blogpost.js"; 
         $spWebPartManager.SaveChanges($webpart);  
         break; 
        }
    }

    SetJSLinkPropertyOnPostsWebPart $SiteURL
```